# Can only iterate over an array or an instance

Tags: java, arrays

I've been trying to get this working for the past hour, I'm getting the error

> Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable

```
public boolean register(Object parent, Class<?>... events) {
    boolean added = false;
    try {
        for (Link<?> link : parentLinkCache.get((List) Objects.requireNonNull(parent, "Object to be registered cannot be null"))) {
            if (events.length > 0) {
                for (Class<?> clazz : events) {
                    if (link.getEventClass() == clazz) {
                        this.backingMap.computeIfAbsent(link.getEventClass(), l -> new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>()).add(link);
                        added = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                this.backingMap.computeIfAbsent(link.getEventClass(), l -> new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>()).add(link);
                added = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return added;
}
```

The error is on `parentLinkCache.get`.

Comment: What type of object does `parentLinkCache.get(...)` return? It's not an array or a type that implements `Iterable<Link<?>>`.

Comment: private static final LoadingCache<Object, Object> parentLinkCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()

Comment: `parentLinkCache.get` returns you an `Object`; that's not `Iterable`.

Answer (score 0):

To use the enhanced for statement.

```
for ( {VariableModifier} UnannType VariableDeclaratorId : Expression ) Statement
```

The type of the Expression must be Iterable or an array type , or a compile-time error occurs. Check the return type of parentLinkCache.get(...).

You can see JLS [The enhanced for statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-EnhancedForStatement)

Answer (score 0):

Your cache should be listing links for every parent. So,

Replace

```
LoadingCache<Object, Object> parentLinkCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder();
```

with

```
LoadingCache<Object, List<Link<?>>> parentLinkCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build();
```

Since List is also an Iterable, you would be able to use it in the [enhanced for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-EnhancedForStatement).

---

Also,

```
CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
```

returns a `CacheBuilder`. If you want a `Cache`, you should write

```
CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. When i do that, i get The method get(Objects.requireNonNull(parent, "Object to be unregistered cannot be null")) is undefined for the type CacheBuilder<Object,Object>

Comment: If you replace the prescribed type, the `parentLinkCache` will not be of type `CacheBuilder<Object,Object>`, it will be of type `LoadingCache<Object, List<Link<?>>>`